# calculate response time from log timestamps entries

Tags: linux, logs, timestamps

I am new to this scripting world, and trying to learn things in my limited time.
Could someone help me compose a script that will get me response time from my log.

The current log format is:

```
2017-05-26 15:38:15,15224 [Dispatcher-13] INFO  someinforServerHelper  - Received request to host/auth/sessions/xyxyxyxy from IP
2017-05-26 15:38:15,15587 [Dispatcher-13] INFO  infolib.rest.XmlRepresentation  - XML Representation Accepted Encodings : identity--The default encoding with no transformation
2017-05-26 15:38:15,15685 [Dispatcher-13] INFO  info.Component.Server  - more info
2017-05-26 15:38:15        ip   -       ip   port   GET     /auth/sessions/xyxyxyxy       -       200     -       -       3       host
```

My idea was to extract in two files, using `awk`, the timestamp, the Dispatcher, and the session ID.

So I will have one file auth _request

```
2017-05-26 15:38:15,15224 [Dispatcher-13] host/auth/sessions/xyxyxyxy
```

and the second file auth response

```
2017-05-26 15:38:15,15685 [Dispatcher-13] /auth/sessions/xyxyxyxy
```

Now comes the part where I fail.

Can someone assist me with a script that take the input of those two files, reads them line by line comparing the unique id's of the session or/and Dispatcher and make a difference of the timestamps so i can get a number that means actually a response time.

I know there are many easier ways with time `wget`/`curl` but unfortunately those are not available to me.
In my mind he script looks like:

1. read line 1 of file one,
2. compare it to lines in file two until a match is found,
3. calculate timestamps difference and after move to next line in file 1
4. and so on until file 1 or file 2 ends.

I've searched for this over the internet many hours and could not find this exact combination of request.

Comment: I formatted the log so that it was readable. @Haleluia, please check that it's still valid and that you text still makes sense.